# Script IF ELSE is only working on first data in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I can only like the first post not second or third or other...

The image is only changing on the first post.. and other they are not working...

```
        $sqkl = "SELECT id FROM favourite WHERE userid='$mainuserid' AND photoid='$photoid' ";
        $rersult = $conn->query($sqkl);

        if ($rersult->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($rkow = $rersult->fetch_assoc()) {

                ?> 
           <img id="fav" style="float:right;" id="fav" onclick="myFav()" src="images/fav.png" height="22" width="22"> </div>

        <?php
            }
        } else {
           ?>  <img id="fav" style="float:right;" onclick="myFav()" src="images/unfav.png" height="22" width="22"> </div> <?php
        } 

        ?>
 <script>
  var image =  document.getElementById("fav");

    function myFav() {
          if (image.getAttribute('src') == "images/fav.png")
            {

             document.getElementById('fav').src='images/unfav.png';

             }else if (image.getAttribute('src') == "images/unfav.png"){
            document.getElementById('fav').src='images/fav.png';
            }
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you add more information about the context and what you are trying to acheive ? You should also refer to the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Comment: You name all the elements with ID `fav`. IDs must be unique. Instead of using `document.getElementById('fav')`, you can probably use `this`.

Comment: `id` value __must be unique__

Comment: (sql injection)

Comment: hey @Qirel , i have replaced  var image =  document.getElementById("fav"); with var image =  this; but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead of using IDs, use `onclick="myFav(this)"`, thereby passing that exact element into the function. You can use that argument directly instead.

Your query is also vulnerable to SQL injection, and you should use a prepared statement instead.

It would also appear to me as though you're running this query inside another query-loop - if that's the case, you should instead get this query integrated into the outer query, as a query within a loop is bad for performance.

```php
<?php 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM favourite WHERE userid=? AND photoid=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $mainuserid, $photoid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <img style="float:right;" onclick="toggleFavorite(this)" src="images/fav.png" height="22" width="22"> </div>
    <?php 
} else {
    ?>
    <img style="float:right;" onclick="toggleFavorite(this)" src="images/unfav.png" height="22" width="22"> </div>
    <?php 
}
$stmt->close();
```

```
<script>
    function toggleFavorite(element) {
        if (element.getAttribute("src") === "images/fav.png") {
            element.src = "images/unfav.png";
        } else {
            element.src = "images/fav.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: lovely thank you..... it worked... you used element to define in JS thankss...

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is not working, is because all images have the same ID. ID's are unique identifiers, and `document.getElementById("fav");` will only select the first element with that ID.
You can use the `this` keyword in the `myFav` function to reference the clicked image

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP's while loop, you are adding several images with the same ID of "fav". However, as **IDs must be unique**, your Javascript code:

```
var image =  document.getElementById("fav");
```

Will always return the first image, because it assumes there is only one document with this ID.

What you can do instead is to use a class name of "fav" (rather than ID), and then use the below code to get a list of all images:

```
var images =  document.getElementsByClassName("fav");
```

Comment: I haven't voted up or down, but using a class and then using `document.getElementsByClassName("fav")` would probably break the logic - you would need to use `this` element. And since there can be more than 1 row here, we're probably looking at a flawed PHP logic too - either its a query within a loop, or its X rows for favorites, and 1 row if no favorite exist.